# Randomly pick key from dictionary weighted by the keys value

Tags: c#, game, random, hash-map

I was trying to write a function that would get a random card from a dictionary of cards in a players deck weighted by the number of cards of each type you have.
I don't know if the solution I came up with is the fates way of doing something like this and this is something I'm going to be doing a lot per turn because of certain mechanics in the games design. Please let me know if there is something i missed that could help the performance of this code.

For some contexts `_deck._card` is a dictionary with the key being a string and the value being a int. `Dictionary<string, int> _cards`

Also `Nez.Random` is a singleton of my random class for the project. `Random.nextInt(int max)` takes in a int for the max value of the random number.

```
static public int nextInt( int max )
{
    return random.Next( max );
}
```

Code:

```
public string GetRandomCard()
{
    string result = "";
    var totalWeight = 0;

    foreach (var cardNumber in _deck._cards)
        totalWeight += cardNumber.Value;

    var randNumber = Nez.Random.nextInt(totalWeight);

    foreach (var cardNumber in _deck._cards)
    {
        var value = cardNumber.Value;

        if (randNumber >= value)
        {
            randNumber -= value;
        }
        else
        {
            result = cardNumber.Key;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Time complexity O(N^2)
I dont think there is a way to decrease the time complexity but there might be other ways to optimize this code.

Comment: The time complexity of this code in currently O(N^2) My question is if there is a way to get this down to O(N). Or if there is just some small improvements in speed I can do. Like I don't know if creating a int is faster using the var keyword or the int keyword, or if there is even a difference in speed (I think the compiler takes care of this so there wont be a difference but I don't know for sure)

Comment: What do you need `numCardTypes` for when you're not using it?

Comment: @t3chb0t Oh wow I completely missed that I left that in from my first attempt at this function.

 I also noticed that I misspelled result. These changes have been corrected in the code now

Comment: I dont know if I should edit my post with these changes or keep it. Anyone know what is common practice here?

Comment: You can edit the code as long as there are no answers. After that, you should no longer do it. It would be great if you corrected it.

Comment: Are you OK with generating the entire card sequence all at once?  What this becomes (minus the compression provided by using weights) is the generation of a permutation of the card deck (shuffling the deck) then dealing out the cards in their shuffled order.

This has examples (unfortunately, in java), but the algorithm is present and should be easy to adapt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505927/how-to-generate-a-random-permutation-in-java.

(Minor nit: Instead of 'weight', 'frequency' would be a better term to use.)

Comment: I'd like to clarify the intention. Hypothetically, say a player has a deck of 10 cards. 5 cards are labeled "Attack", 3 cards are labeled "Defend", and 2 cards are labeled "Heal". You would represent this with the dictionary `{Attack => 5, Defend => 3, Heal => 2}`? And when the player draws a card, you would call this function, which gives the player a 50% chance of Attacking, a 30% chance of Defending, and a 20% chance of Healing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you will use this class? If you are sampling from a different set of weights every time, then you can't do better than the `O(n)` you already have (per sample); if the sample is the same or a slight variation, then you may be able to do successive samplings in `O(log(n))`

Comment: @benj2240 You are right in the result but the system is there is a class named deck that is used for anything that needs cards and to be able to communicate with other decks. Inside the deck is a dictionary of all the cards this deck has. This dictionary is used as a lightweight and fast way of storing and accessing this data. An example of this dictionary would be {WarLord => 8, Mage => 3, Dragon => 4} I want this function to randomly pick a card but have Warlord have a 8/15 change of getting picked and mage having 3/15 and so on.

Comment: @VisualMelon Yes this function will be sampling from a different set of weights almost every time it is used. The function works for all decks in the game and every deck has a different number and types of cards. Also these decks are having cards added and remove constantly due to how some mechanics of the game work. This is why Im using a dictionary to represent what cards this deck currently has because of the speed to fetch info from it. Then if the game every needs to know more info about what a card is or does, it does a lookup using the name(string) of the cards type.

Comment: Could you provide a little more info concerning how the probabilities change and cards are added/removed? You can do all of these operations in `O(log(n))` time with a suitable data-structure, so it the number of changes is small compared to the deck size, then that might be worth investigating. If the decks are size 3 as in your answer, then the complexity doesn't really matter, and it won't be worth anything more complicated than a linear scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all this good discussion It looks like this function is as optimize as its going to get for its intended purpose. 
I want to note that I was incorrect in its time complexity. The time complexity is actually O(N) not O(N^2) luckily.

Considering this algorithm can perform 1,000 random selections in 0.00194s on a mid range workstation It shouldn't have any performance impact if used many times.

Here are the results of the unit test:

```
Running random 100 times: 0.0013367s
Key: 30%, Value: 35
Key: 60%, Value: 60
Key: 10%, Value: 5

Running random 1000 times: 0.0019477s
Key: 30%, Value: 378
Key: 60%, Value: 618
Key: 10%, Value: 104

Running random 10000 times: 0.0202942s
Key: 30%, Value: 3391
Key: 60%, Value: 6635
Key: 10%, Value: 1074

Running random 100000 times: 0.191678s
Key: 30%, Value: 33669
Key: 60%, Value: 66427
Key: 10%, Value: 11004

Running random 1000000 times: 1.77491s
Key: 30%, Value: 334075
Key: 60%, Value: 666087
Key: 10%, Value: 110938

Running random 10000000 times: 18.43691s
Key: 30%, Value: 3332173
Key: 60%, Value: 6667785
Key: 10%, Value: 1111142
```

Comment: I love it. So often the answer to "How do I optimize this" is "You probably don't need to." Since you took the extra step to actually measure, this time the answer is definite. Plus, you confirmed that the probability distribution is working as you intended. Nicely done.

Comment: I'm confused by your results... The sum of your Values doesn't add up to the number of times except for the first case (100). E.g. 1,000 -> 1,100, 10,000 -> 11,000, 100,000 -> 111,100 etc. Do you have a bug in your test or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @RobH Wow I didn't even notice that. Thank you for pointing that out! Im unable to check the code and test again because it is on my work computer but I will look into once im back at work in 4 days.

Comment: These are exactly the results we would expect if the counters were cumulative across the test runs.

Comment: @benj2240 Thats most likely it. I don't remember if I reset the results dic ever time I did the test (I doubt I did). If it is then it would not effect the test in any way,

Comment: @benj2240 - yes, that's what I assumed was happening too but I didn't want to lead the witness ;)

Answer (score 1):

You've covered the performance and correctness of your code, so all I can comment on is style.

**Linq:** When possible, I prefer a declarative style of programming over an imperative style. That is, saying *what* you want instead of *how* to calculate it. Linq makes this easy in the case of totalWeight, which could be declared like this:

```csharp
var totalWeight = _deck._cards.Sum(cardNumber => cardNumber.Value);
```

Technically the second `foreach` could also be transformed into a Linq statement, using `.Aggregate()` and `.First()`... But I don't recommend it, as in that case I believe it would actually be *less* readable.

---

**Immediate returns:** Between the following two functions, I prefer the latter:

```csharp
int Foo1(Bar bar)
{
    var answer = 0;

    if (bar != null)
    {
        answer = bar.Baz;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

```csharp
int Foo2(Bar bar)
{
    if (bar == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return bar.Baz;
}
```

In `Foo2`, I don't have to mentally track the state of the `answer` variable as I read. Another benefit is that `Foo2` scratches that itch I get when I see a bad variable name... "answer" is only a tiny bit more informative than "x", as variable names go.

So I would refactor your code to remove the `result` variable completely. On the line where you set it, just `return cardNumber.Key`.

---

**Defaults vs Exceptions:** I would also change the line where you `return result`. Instead, just throw an Exception. You seem to have tested your code pretty well, so you can be confident that the exception will never be thrown... Until the code is refactored, or the card weights are changed to Floats, or who-knows-what.

If that ever happens, an exception saying "The weighted card drawing function failed to select a card" will be easier to debug than an exception saying "Player cannot summon '': invalid unit type."

As a side note, yes I *would* prefer a third version of my function above. If you're going to fail, fail fast!

```csharp
int Foo3(Bar bar)
{
    if (bar == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bar));

    return bar.Baz;
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot `Sum()` was a function in dictionary's! As for the Immediate returns I personally prefer the former because returning 0 is a expected response to this call. There are decks that at time will have no cards in them at all  (_cards will still be a dictionary just with 0 keys). This point also falls into why this function doesn't need a exception because there is no unexpected result that is still a number.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original question was about efficiency, here's how you achieve the same thing enumerating the dictionary once...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CodeReviewFun
{
  static class Program
  {
    private static Random _random = new Random();
    private static Dictionary<string, int> _dict;
    private static Dictionary<string, int> _hits;
    private static int _nCardTypes;
    private static int _nCatds;

    static Program()
    {
      _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
      _hits = new Dictionary<string, int>();
      _dict.Add("WarLord", 8);
      _dict.Add("Mage", 3);
      _dict.Add("Dragon", 4);
      _nCardTypes = _dict.Count;
      _nCatds = 0;
      foreach (var cardTypeKey in _dict.Keys)
      {
        _hits.Add(cardTypeKey, 0);
        _nCatds += _dict[cardTypeKey];
      }
    }

    //  The idea is that Value * randomNumber is already weighted
    //  so just remember the key for the most heavily weighted value and the corresponding key
    //  and return that
    public static string GetRandomCard()
    {
      string pick_Key = "";
      int pick_Value = -1;
      foreach (var entry in _dict)
      {
        int pick = _random.Next(_nCardTypes);
        int thisValue = pick * entry.Value;
        if (thisValue > pick_Value)
        {
          pick_Key = entry.Key;
          pick_Value = thisValue;
        }
      }
      return pick_Key;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      const int nSamples = 10000000;
      for (int i = 0; i < nSamples; i++)
      {
        var hitKey = GetRandomCard();
        _hits[hitKey]++;
      }
      foreach (var entry in _hits)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key, -10}: {entry.Value} ({(double)entry.Value * _nCatds / _nCardTypes})");
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Sample run:

```
WarLord   : 7037889 (35189445)
Mage      : 1112616 (5563080)
Dragon    : 1849495 (9247475)
```

Comment: I original had this idea put unfortunately decks are gaining and losing card all the time (It can be up to 100 times per micro turn in some very extreme but possible cases (a micro turn is just a subsection of a turn)) so the weight needs to be calculate every time

Comment: @TylerGregorcyk how large are the decks? how many different types of card are there?

Comment: Then you're heading for trouble.  If the totalWeight calculated in the 1st enumeration exceeds the total of the values encountered in the 2nd enumeration pass, then you can generate a random number that exceeds the new total and return a result of "".  If this possibility breaks your logic, you should (a) minimise the number of enumeration passes and (b) consider making judicious use of lock(s) to protect the bits of code that update the values.  Otherwise you're just setting up a target that you know won't stand still while you're shooting at it.

Comment: @VisualMelon These decks very in size from 0-500. This is because the object `deck` is used for anything that needs cards and needs to be able to move cards around from its self to other decks and vice versa. So for example the players hand is just a `deck` object and the players playing deck is also a `deck` object. As to how many cards, as of right now there are planned to be 150 different types of cards but this can be expanded as needed (And most likely will be)

Comment: @AlanK This should not be a issue because all request to move or edit a deck is through a [command system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and all commands make sure they are on the same thread as the data they are manipulating.